# How do I set up ACS in SQL Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, acs

How do I set up ACS in SQL Azure?

I am trying  a code sample from Azure that is to create a custom Login Page in ASP.NET and MVC 3.

It claims to use the ACS Management Portal. It instructs to log on to the my Azure homepage and "navigate to the Service Bus, Access Control and Cashing section."  Where is that?  I do not see this on my Azure homepage.

The example is listed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh127794.aspx

The step says:

> To configure the sample via the ACS Management Portal
>
> 1. Open a browser, navigate to the Windows Azure homepage (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=130560), and sign in. Navigate
>      to the Service Bus, Access Control, and Caching section to configure
>      your ACS service namespace. Once you have created a namespace, select
>      it and click Manage > Access Control Service, located at the top of
>      the page. This will launch the page in a new window.

Where is that?  I do not see this on my Azure homepage.

http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/AZURE/whereistheservicebus.png

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is the new preview portal (I'm referencing your screenshot). In order to access all features of your Azure subscription you might also need to use the 'old' Silverlight portal. Today this is still the case for ACS.

You can visit the old portal through this URL: https://windows.azure.com/